# How to disable Fast Boot (Fast Startup, Hybrid Boot) only once by the next shutdown?

Tags: windows, winapi

The problem is;

Our software (setup) detects that the computer (win10), it is running on, needs to be restarted due to file operations, other setups and so on. Then we are asking for *restart now* or *later* to continue.

If the user **restarts** the computer immediately or later, pending operations have been done, and all is ok. But if the user only does **shutdown** (from start menu) and later starts the computer up again (there is a Fast Boot) pending operations would not been done. It is clear, because of fast boot...

My question is; How can i programatically say windows to disable fast boot only **once** by the next shutdown? I don't want disable it completely and activate it after next startup. Is it possible?

Comment: for enable/disable Fast Startup need under key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power` change `HiberbootEnabled` `REG_DWORD` - *0 = Turn off fast startup, 1 = Turn on fast startup*. but this will be permanent until you not change this back.

Comment: of course if direct call `ExitWindowsEx` or `InitiateSystemShutdownEx` or `InitiateShutdown` possible do full reboot without change this option

Comment: @RbMm thank you, but permanent changes doesn't help as you guessed. It is only a problem if user goes to StartMenu->Shutdown. I'm not sure whether it is possible to say disable fast boot only once for the next time, but how does WindowsUpdate do the work without fresh restart?

Comment: you can register self app under `RunOnce` for revert change of `HiberbootEnabled` after reboot. but think no option only once change this. and this is not documented (`HiberbootEnabled`)

Comment: @RbMm but does the program started via RunOnce have the necessary credentials to change values under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE?

Comment: @Jabberwocky - in my test yes - explorer (even if it medium level) exec `runonce.exe /explorer`  as admin (so elevated) and already `runonce.exe`  exec entries from `RunOnce` key elevated. even notepad from here will be run elevated. exec one by one - wait until previous exe not exit before run new

Comment: @Jabberwocky - can be done next easy check - register for run `cmd.exe /c whoami /priv /groups > c:\windows\temp\ww.log` and then check `c:\windows\temp\ww.log` file. i view `High Mandatory Level Label` and another admin groups/privs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of RbMm on the comments of the answer I did this script which disables the Hybrid boot and adds a command to the RunOnce key in the registry to reenable it on the next boot.

The batch needs to be run with administrator rights:

```
@ECHO OFF
%COMSPEC% /C reg add "hklm\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /v HiberbootEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /F

%COMSPEC% /C REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v DisableHiberbootOnce /t REG_SZ /d "%COMSPEC% /C reg add """hklm\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power""" /v HiberbootEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /F
```

As RbMm said the HLKM `RunOnce` key only it's executed if one administrator logins on the computer. To fix this I run on a GPO computer login script the command `runonce.exe /explorer` which runs the RunOnce scripts on the HKLM registry key without the need to log in as administrator.